# I dont understand where is the exit condition of this loop for

Tags: python, stdin

in class there is some code with for loop and i dont find the exit condition. Can anyone help me

```
import sys 
summe = 0 

for zeile in sys.stdin:  
   summe += float(zeile) 
print(summe)
```

Also, i already run the code above in idle python and it always produces error. This code is from my teacher. So could it be wrong ?

many thanks in advance

Comment: The `for` loop is iterating over input from stdin.  When EOF is reached, the loop will exit.

Comment: Please post the error. Python usually writes the error message when it occurs.

Comment: Note: you can press Ctrl+D in the console to send an EOF character.

Comment: error: summe += float(zeile)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Apparently `zelle` is not a number-like string. Do you enter more than one number per line?

Comment: EOF = end of file, there is no file here, but input from users. how does python know when i want to stop giving input? by entering a special icon? by hitting " space" key or ? 
i am sorry i feel so silly asking this.

I only enter one number per line. But i am more concerned how this loop knows when to end. is there any implicit exit condition i am not aware ?.

Comment: Thank you Blorgbeard, i dont know such EOF character exist. Why my teacher doesnt include that is beyond me. it all makes sense now